# Angular2: date pipe with async pipe

Tags: angular

I'm setting this code in order to print out a subscription feed date field:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
  <span class="text-light fs-mini m">
    {{((user$ | async).validation) | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Angular is telling me:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: co.user is undefined

I've to say that the problem appears when I've added `date` pipe. `(user$|async).valitation` works fine without formatting.

Comment: try this `{{((user$ | async)?.validation) | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}`

Comment: It keeps failing...

Comment: could you add more code in your component `user$`

Comment: @Jordi `((user$ | async)?.validation)` resolves to `undefined` which in return is passed to your date pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((user$ | async).validation)` resolves to `undefined` which is then passed to the date pipe.

I would suggest you resolve what either with a `subscription` in your component and then:

```
 <div class="col-xs-8">
  <span class="text-light fs-mini m">
    {{ user.validation | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Or something similar to this:

```
 <div class="col-xs-8">
  <span *ngIf="user$ | async" class="text-light fs-mini m">
    {{ user$.validation | async | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Or create a custom [date pipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts#L15-L143) that accepts observables as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As of Angular 6 (I thinkl) You could use the `as` syntak too on the async.

```
 <div class="col-xs-8">
  <span *ngIf="user$ | async as user" class="text-light fs-mini m">
    {{ user.validation | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
  </span>
</div>
```

This article is worth a read [Handling Observables with NgIf and the Async Pipe](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-async-pipe)